# how to convert numbers to strings and push them into an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was solving an exercise with array methods; where I was expected to input a number and the returned value should be the same number with dashes between each two consecutive even numbers.

I have wrote this code so far but It's returning an empty array, It would be much better if you could point out my mistakes than giving an alternative solution.

```
function dashit(num){ 
   //test num = 025468, expected arr = ["0","-","2","5","4","-","6","-  ","8"]
    var arr = [];
    var prog = num.toString().split(""); // I suppose ["0","2","5","4","6","8"]
    for (var i = 0; i<num.length; i = i + 2){
        if (num[i] % 2 == 0 ){ // case of "0" and "2"
            if (num[i+1] % 2 == 0){
                arr.push(prog[i]); // "0" pushed from prog to arr
                arr.push("-");     // "-" pushed from prog to arr
                arr.push(prog[i+1]); // "2" pushed from prog to arr
            }
        }
        else { // case of "5" and "4"
                arr.push(prog[i]);  // "5" pushed from prog to arr
                arr.push(prog[i+1]); // "4" pushed from prog to arr
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I suppose `num` is an actual number (as in the comment), and `num[i]` doesn't make sense, but your debugger will tell you everything you need to know

Comment: `num.length` is `undefined`. Did you mean `prog.length`? Same with all the other `num` uses. Why are you using `num` in same cases and `prog` in others?

Comment: If you know num contains just numbers, you could use parseInt(num) to get an integer.  If it could contain some junk characters, a `/(\d+)/` regex may be more suitable.  Is there any reason you're rolling your own solution?

Comment: @Amit I am not using a debugger, I've learned programming recently and was solving exercises

Comment: You are using javascript strings like C strings- they are not. To extract a specific character use substring() method, however in your code **prog** is an array of characters, you are using **num** which is still an integer.

Comment: Then you should [learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en) ASAP! Otherwise, how you will be able to verify or fix your code?

Comment: @FelixKling does that mean numbers don't have index or length?

Comment: @Tibrogargan RegExp is such a pain in the arse, I feel like it's too early for me as a beginner to learn it

Comment: @ArifBurhan never used C before :)

Comment: Ok, so look at the documentation for String.slice, it may be more use than split

Comment: *"does that mean numbers don't have index or length?"* Yes. Maybe reading a tutorial would be helpful: http://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html .

Comment: @FelixKling - "*how you will be able to verify ... your code*", well... TDD comes in as a handy methodology. A colleague of mine **regularly** declares "I never debug my code" (with the subtext being "I **test** it")

Comment: @Amit: Fair enough :D But you still need to debug the code somehow when the tests don't pass, don't you? :)

Comment: @FelixKling - it's tedious to do and very hard to master (not there myself - yet!), but with proper tests and proper design (SOLID principles, small units, etc..) you really don't have to... But this is really some utopian idea that's not suitable for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `num` as `octal` number(starts with 0)

Try pass it as a `string`

```
dashit("025468");
```

---

See working example:

```js
function dashit(num){ 
  
    var arr = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i<num.length; i = i + 2){
        if (num[i] % 2 == 0 ){ // case of "0" and "2"
            if (num[i+1] % 2 == 0){
                arr.push(num[i]); // "0" pushed from prog to arr
                arr.push("-");     // "-" pushed from prog to arr
                arr.push(num[i+1]); // "2" pushed from prog to arr
            }
        }
        else { // case of "5" and "4"
                arr.push(num[i]);  // "5" pushed from prog to arr
                arr.push(num[i+1]); // "4" pushed from prog to arr
                arr.push("-");
        }
    }
    return arr;
} 


document.write(JSON.stringify(dashit("025468")));
```

Comment: thanks alot for your input, it actually worked but for some reason only 1 dash is missing between 4 and 6

Comment: @MohamedHegazy you forget add `arr.push("-");` in `else` statement, I've updated the code, please see

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing your `num` var, you have to compare the `prog` var :

```
    function dashit(num){ 
    var prog = num.toString().split(""); // I suppose ["0","2","5","4","6","8"]
    for (var i = 0; i<prog.length; i = i + 2){
        if (prog[i] % 2 == 0 ){ // case of "0" and "2"
            if (prog[i+1] % 2 == 0){
}
```

Comment: Always willing to help :D

Answer (score 0):

This problem is perfect for the use of recursion. I'm certain that's what your teacher wanted ;-)

```js
var n = '02546878642';

var isPair = function(n1, n2) {
  return Number(n1) % 2 == 0 && Number(n2) % 2 == 0;
};

var result = (function f(i, o) {

  if (i.length < 1) return o;
  var first = i.shift();
  var next =  i[0];
  o.push(first);
  if (isPair(first, next)) {
    o.push('-');
  }
  return f(i, o);
})(n.split(''), []);



$('#result').html(result.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'>result</div>
```